# Comparing permissions of an existing file/directory with those of what would be created

Tags: permissions, acl

Suppose I'm creating a file or directory with some name and mode argument using a system call and that operations fails with `EEXIST`.

Assuming I know my current `umask`, `euid`, and `egid`, how can I tell if that existing file/directory has permissions equivalent to what the  system call would have created had the operation succeeded.

AFAIK, for classical permissions, the answer would be true iff
`.st_gid == egid && .st_uid == euid && (.st_mode & 07777) == (RequestedMode & 07777 & ~CurrentUmask)` and the found/expected filetypes match.

How could this be extended to a system with access control lists?

Comment: Don't forget the setgid bit on the containing directory. And then there's stuff like SELinux...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend this to ACLs, you’d call [`acl_get_file`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/acl_get_file.3.html) with the path in which you’re creating the file, and `ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT` to request the default ACL on the directory. If there is one, that’s the ACL that would be applied by default to the file you tried to create.

You’d then use `acl_get_file` on the existing file, with `ACL_TYPE_ACCESS`, to retrieve the actual ACL on the file.

I don’t think there’s an ACL function for comparing ACLs, so that’s left as an exercise for the reader.